# Remove duplicates in column of MySQL data

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that was created from data output by another application.

On of the columns is for an email address, however the data in this column is all duplicates.

For example, the `email` for a single record looks like this:

```
user@example.com,user@example.com
```

I would like the field to contain the address just once.

Is there a way through a MySQL command, to remove anything from the `,` onward?

I know I can write a PHP script to loop through all the data, but i was hoping there was a simpler way through MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way through a MySQL command, to remove anything from the `,` onward?

For this you should use the [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

```
UPDATE directory SET contactEmail = SUBSTRING_INDEX(contactEmail, ',', -1);
```

but before you run `UPDATE` on real data, please have a backup or perform the test on another table.

Comment: I just tried it, and it said 0 rows were modified. Hmm

Comment: Still nothing, using this

Comment: UPDATE directory SET contactEmail = TRIM( LEADING ',' FROM contactEmail ) WHERE 1=1;